# Why does the norm of a linear functional $T$ satisfy $\|T\|_*=\sup\{|T(f)|\mid f \in X, \|f\|\leq 1\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

For a normed linear space $X$, a linear functional on $X$ is said to be bounded provided there is an $M \geq 0$ for which $|T(f)|\leq M\|f\|$ for all $f \in X$. Denote $\|T\|_*$ the infinmum of all such $M$.

> Why is the following equality true?
>   $$\|T\|_*=\sup\{|T(f)|:f \in X, \|f\|\leq 1\}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $N=sup\{\|T(f)\|, \|f\|=1\}$. Let $f\neq 0$, $\|T({f\over\|f\|})\|\leq N$ since $T$ is linear, we deduce $\|T(f)\|\leq N\|f\|$ thus $N\geq M$.

On the other hand,for every $f$ such that $\|f\|=1$, $\|T(f)\|\leq M\|f\|=M$ this implies that $N=sup\{\|T(f)\|, \|f\|=1\}\leq M$

Comment: Seems like the second half only proves N<=M when ||F||=1

Comment: Since you know that $N\geq M$ to show that $N=M$ it is enough to show that $N\leq M$, you can use for that the set of $f$ such that $\|f\|=1$.

Comment: i think I see what you meant. Is it right to say that  ∥T(f)∥ / ||f|| =  ∥T(f/||f||)∥?

Comment: If $\|f\|<1, $\|T(f)\|$<{1\over{\|f\|}}\|T(f)\|=\|T({f\over{\|f\|}})\leq N$. This implies that $sup\{\|T(f)\|, \|f\|\leq 1\}=sup\{\|T(f)\|, \|f\|=1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The equality gives you an equivalent definition of the norm of a bounded linear functional. A proof is given [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Definitions_of_Norm_of_Linear_Functional).