# Can anyone help understand one step in the proof of a theoeam related to the norm of linear functional?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

> **Proposition 2** Let $E$ be a measurable set, $1 < p < \infty$, $q$ the conjugate of $p$, and $g$ belong to $L^q(E)$. Define the functional $T$ on $L^p(E)$ by $$T(f)=\int_E gf\quad \hbox{for all } f\in L^p(E)$$ Then $T$ is a bounded linear functional on LP(E)
> and $||T||_*=||g||_q$
>
> **Proof** T is a bounded
> linear functional on LP(E) and II T11" < ll gllq. On the other hand,
> the conjugate function of g, $$g* = ||g||^{q-1} sgn(g)|g|^{q-1}$$, belongs to LP(E), $$T(g*)=\|g\|_q \ and\ \|g*\|_p=1$$ It follows that $||T||_*=||g||_q$

I do not get the last step. Why is this true $||T||_*=||g||_q$? Isnt $||T||_*$ defined as an infimum?

Comment: It's defined as the infimum on the unit ball (or sphere, but that's equivalent thanks to linearity). But why does that bother you?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1807735/9464

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that $$\|T\| = \sup_{\| f\|_p =1} | Tf|,$$
then $$| Tf| \leq \|g\|_q \|f\|_p $$
implies $$\| T\| \leq \|g\|_q.$$
What is shown in the last line is that the "less or equal" is actually an equality since you found a function, namely $g*$ for which 
$$|Tg*| = \| g\|_q$$
holds.